# Using running totals in MS access report cumulatively

Tags: ms-access

I am developing a db (MS access 2010) to support a school with a well-defined model for tuition quotation.  The list of products is assembled for each quote, then various discounts are applied.  The discounts may be a percentage or an absolute dollar amount.  So far, so easy.  The problem is that their business logic requires:

1. No limit on number of discounts.
2. Specific discounts to be applied in a defined sequence (implemented in my case with a "discount ordinal" column, values 1 (first applied) to 100 (last applied).
3. Each sequential application of a discount is to the **running total** of the quote.  Eg: Total products $1000.  Discount: 50%. Value: $500. Subtotal $500.
   Subtotal: $500.  Discount: $25. Value: $25. Subtotal: $475.
   Subtotal: $475.  Discount: $10%. Value: $47.50. Subtotal: $427.50.

This appears to be a variation of the "get the value of the field in the previous row" problem, but with the added twist that the "value of the field" is actually a cumulative calculation.  It has the flavor of recursion: while discounts remain, subtotal(previous subtotal).

I have no clear idea how to implement this in a report, because the calculation as noted above is self-referential.  I'm not looking for code here, just guidance on the general approach to the problem (ie, some kind of global variable, using VBA - in which case, I'm not sure what the "glue" between the query in VBA and the report would be - or some trick with a calculated field although I've spent a lot of time trying to figure one out).  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you need to assign your variable using the prior variable i.e. `i = i + 1` so `value (v) = $1000, v = v*0.5,v=v*0.9` You could assign the discount to another variable say d so it would become: `v = v * d`

Answer (score 1):

In that kind of situations, I always create a new table, that will get filled up when the report opens, and base the report in that table, not the original one. That way I can do all the calculations I need, even making several passes. The report then is simply a "dump" of the table. Complex totals can be additional columns, that will be shown only in the totals section.

Answer (score 0):

You could have table for purchase history using an integer to link each purchase since an autonumber by itself will not link each discount stage.

So in excel I would use something like this:

```
v = Starting Value
i = 1

Do Until i = Last Discount
    d = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
    v = v * (1 - d)
    ws.Range("B2").Value = v
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

At each stage you could write to the table (using `docmd.runsql`) the discount applied (d) and the value (v) but it could be quite slow. You could then order the table by purchase identifier then descending by value since sequential discounts will inherently order correctly.